# How do I change what variable is being used?

Tags: python, variables

I have a task to ask the user how many directions they have for a Finch robot in python.
After I have how many directions there are, I need to ask and save each one of those.
What I can't figure out is how to switch which variable I am using and still store the user's answer.

```
count = 1

nod = int(input("How many directions do you have?: ")) #nod = number of directions
for int in range(0, nod):
    d1 = str(input("Direction " + str(count) + ": ")) 
        #I want to switch out d1 with d2,d3, etc. for as many directions as the user has
count += 1
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Answer (score 5):

In that case, don't use single variables but a list:

```
directions = []
nod = int(input("How many directions do you have?: ")) #nod = number of directions
for i in range(nod):
    directions.append(input("Direction {}: ".format(i+1)))
```

If you're using Python 3, you don't need to call `str()` on `input()`'s result. If you're on Python 2, use `raw_input()` instead.

Note that you don't need the `count` variable since `nod` already contains that information. (And you can always call `len(directions)` later). Be aware that the first direction is `direction[0]` since Python counts starting with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list instead of individual variables.